# How to set name for FormGroup?

Tags: angular, angular8

I need to set unique name for FormGroup:

```
let controls = {};
let formName = "Form1";
const form = new FormGroup(controls);
```

How to set name `formName` for `new FormGroup`?

Comment: Why do you need to set unique name for a `FormGroup`? What problem are you trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: Problem is that `const form` does not have property `name` or method to do that

Comment: I am aware of that. Why do you need to name the form group in the first place?

Comment: Because I have json that represents all relations between forms, and  by form name I can find child forms

Comment: @OPV why don't you use an array with indexes in your json?

Comment: You mean add concrete `new FormGroup` to array by string key as name of form?

Comment: @OPV yes this kind of thing

Comment: or you could create an object like `[{formName:"hello", form: new FormGroup}]`

Comment: Last comment is fit for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never seen a `name` attribute in `formGroup`.

One option if you have multiple forms would be to create an array filled with objects as so

```
forms:any = 
 [
  {
   formName:'myForm',
   form: new FormGroup(control)
  }
 ]
```

one other solution (and I don't know how your app is built) if you use a more "dynamic" approach would be to retrieve the indexes in your json

```
...subscribe((data:any)=>{
   if (data.formIndex > -1 && data.formIndex < this.forms.length)
     this.actualForm = this.forms[data.formIndex]
})
```

Comment: you lose a lot of form control capability with this approach for questionable gains

Comment: hey @bryan60 can you give an example please?

Comment: any tracking of the state / events on the overall form, really all form group functionality, getting sub forms and subscribing to events via .get(), using form group directives in template, the idea of a named form is already built into the concept of the formgroup by the nature of it's keyed object structure. building / maintaining this array and data structure is not needed

Answer (score 3):

it sounds like you want a form group with sub form groups, example using form builder for ease:

```
this.masterForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  "Form1": this.formBuilder.group({ ... whatever controls ... })
})
```

repeat / nest as needed.